# Convert File to DocumentFile

Tags: android, android-file, documentfile

I want to convert `File` (`/storage/A54E-14E9/bp.mp4`) to `DocumentFile`

`Uri` of `DocumentFile` should be `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/A54E-14E9%3A/document/A54E-14E9%3Abp.mp4`

but when I use `DocumentFile.fromFile(file).getUri()` it returns not correct `Uri`:

```
file:///storage/A54E-14E9/bp.mp4
```

So it's different than when you get it in `onActivityResult` after calling `startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_ACCESS);`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_ACCESS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri treeUri = data.getData();
            mDocumentDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
            for (DocumentFile file : mDocumentDir.listFiles()) {
                // one of them is content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/A54E-14E9%3A/document/A54E-14E9%3Abp.mp4
                Log.i(TAG, file.getUri());
            }
        }
    }
```

or if it's not possible then how to find what equals to `File` (`/storage/A54E-14E9/bp.mp4`) in:

```
// in onActivityResult
for (DocumentFile file : mDocumentDir.listFiles()) {
    Log.i(TAG, file.getUri());
}
```

it's not good idea to just check file names, I need to check absolute paths (if they equals),  also file can be placed in subfodler, so it makes things more difficult

My task is to delete `File` from *MicroSD card*, it can be done using `DocumentFile` after requesting storage (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) but I need somehow to get the right `DocumentFile` which equals my `File`

Comment: `Uri of DocumentFile should be content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/A54E-14E9%3A/document/A54E-14E9%3Abp.mp4`. Yes but only if you started with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Not when you picked the file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Please try.

Comment: But then... Why not write a small function that builds the correct uri? Its not that difficult.

Comment: For the rest it is strange that you start with a file system path to a file you wanna delete. How did you obtain it? But you should not mess around with such paths. You should only use content schemes.

Comment: @greenapps I just used `listFiles` on a directory to get normal file paths because I use recyclerview (I don't want to use intent tree just to show available files... it would annoy users), anyway I found this hack: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/blob/master/vlc-android/src/org/videolan/vlc/util/FileUtils.java#L296 you can pass `Uri.fromFile(file)` as parameter

Comment: That is a hack. And in order to let the hack work you have once let the user choose the SD card using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. So you could do that before listing 'files' in the recycleview as well.

Comment: @greenapps yes I know (at least only once). it's Google fault we're trying to find alternatives because have are we supposed to delete a file (absolute path) from sd card if we can't even convert it easily to documentfile, we of course can show a message to a user which would say: find & delete manually the file you need in that annoying dialog tree, but I don't think he would like to use this difficult way

Comment: You should list files using the directory content scheme obtained by ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Then you do not have to do any conversion. Adapt to modern times!

Comment: On Android 7+ you can use StorageVolumes. Then the user does not even have to select the SD card. Only confirm a permission to use it.

Comment: @greenapps but we should use File (not DocumentFile) for some directory to get list of video files for example https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fd-Vx2JsvAkhtzanvExidgNz0dJZ3Y9UJsxl-niXZK1kPe876N44o2oYAH-RZPQ-f0Js=w1920-h949-rw

Comment: No. Not at all. You can use the Storage Access Framework for all. Try ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and you see what all you can get: all you see. @user155